# SQL query to get results in a very specific order by date descending AND with multiple 'like' clause

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a SQL query but having some real struggle and unsure the best way to write it. I currently have 2 columns, one containing timestamps, the other containing random information. I want the timestamps to be in descending order (easy enough), but for the secondary column, i want to output the result in the following order

NOTE: the % are intentional as they are in the REMAINING column.

1. '%[EVENT=agentStateEvent]%' - first
2. %[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%' - second
3. what ever else third,forth etc for that time stamp.

for example:

Both columns are strings (varchar max)

```
    TIMESTAMP       | REMAINING
    TIMESTAMP 10:30 | %[EVENT=agentStateEvent][Agentid=424][Queue=45235]%
    TIMESTAMP 10:30 | %[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated][Agentid=424][Queue=45235]%
    TIMESTAMP:10.31 | %[EVENT=agentStateEvent][Agentid=425][Queue=453635]%
    TIMESTAMP 10.31 | %[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated][Agentid=425][Queue=45235]%
    TIMESTAMP 10.31 | %[EVENT=CallDropped][Agentid=425][Queue=45235]%
    TIMESTAMP 10.32 | %[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated][Agentid=426][Queue=44235]%
    TIMESTAMP 10.32 | %[EVENT=CallDropped][Agentid=426][Queue=45235]%
```

It would need to be wrapped in a 'like' command as the column REMAINING contains alot more information.

query i have so far is :

```
select * from TimestampsStorage
order by timestamp desc, remaining desc
```

Comment: Please post an example of the complete contents of both the `timestamp` and `remaining` columns. It is not clear what the format of either is, though I think I understand that you are using `%...%` to imply that these are substrings in `remaining`.

Comment: Hi, both columns are strings (varchar max). The %.....% are not substrings, they are actually part of the string i.e. the actual entry in the REMAINING column is %[hithere]%. If i wanted to do a search, it would be select * from timestampsStorage where remaining = '%[hithere]%' if that makes sense?

Comment: But you said "_It would need to be wrapped in a 'like' command as the column REMAINING contains alot more information._" What is the other information? Please edit above to post at least one full example.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Its definately not oracle, so presume postgres? Im doing all this via SQL Server Express

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - edited my post. It still shortened compared to whats in the database because theres over 20,000 characters in each of the REMAINING row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `CASE ... WHEN`:

```
order by 
  timestamp, 
  case when remaining like '%[EVENT=agentStateEvent]%' then 1
       when remaining like '%[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%' then 2
       else 3
  end;
```

In case `'%[EVENT=...'` comes always first in `remaining`, you can look for '%' explicitley. This may speed up the query.

```
order by 
  timestamp, 
  case when remaining like '#%[EVENT=agentStateEvent]%' escape '#' then 1
       when remaining like '#%[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%' escape '#' then 2
       else 3
  end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a case expression in the ORDER BY clause

```
select ...
ORDER BY
      [TIMESTAMP]
    , CASE WHEN [REMAINING] = '%[EVENT=agentStateEvent]%' then 1
           WHEN [REMAINING] = '%[EVENT=TerminalConnectionCreated]%' THEN 2
           ELSE 3
      END
    , [REMAINING]
```

NB: as I'm not sure which dbms you are using; the [] is used in T-SQL